# Fused Location Provider only working on some phones

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, fusedlocationproviderapi

Update 1: I figured out that the code does actually work, but it doesn't ask for permission to use your location. If you go to the app permissions and give it location access manually it works. I still don't know how to get it to ask for permissions for location on runtime.

I'm learning about fused location provider and made an app just to display lat and long. I'm using my LG G4 with 6.0 and followed this great [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QazGb6wJed8&list=PLpg_vSyqsFdoxekCSLdZgwx_Emlr3LRa0), but when i run it on my phone it just shows the lat and long text not the gps coordinates. I tested it on a Motorolla X 2015 and Moto Droid Turbo and it works.

compile SDK version: 7.0
Gradle Version: 2.14.1
Android Plugin Version: 2.2.0
Build Tools Version: 24.0.2

Manifest:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.nathan.gpstest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Gradle Dependancies:

```js
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
}
```

MainActivity:

```js
package com.example.nathan.gpstest;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

  TextView latitudeText;
  TextView longitudeText;
  private FusedLocationProviderApi locationProvider = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
  private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
  private LocationRequest locationRequest;
  private double myLatitude;
  private double mylongitude;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    latitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);
    longitudeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLongitude);


    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
      .addApi(LocationServices.API)
      .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
      .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
      .build();

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(15 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    requestLocationUpdates();
  }

  private void requestLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      // TODO: Consider calling
      //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
      // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
      //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
      //                                          int[] grantResults)
      // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
      // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
      return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    latitudeText.setText("Connection Suspended");
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    latitudeText.setText("Connection Failed");

  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    myLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mylongitude = location.getLongitude();

    latitudeText.setText("Latitude : " + String.valueOf(myLatitude));
    //latitudeText.setText("Latitude : " + String.valueOf(myLatitude));
    longitudeText.setText("Longitude : " + String.valueOf(mylongitude));
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
      requestLocationUpdates();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check these links [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), [sample usage](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Location/FusedNew/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/weather2/AbstractGoogleApiClientActivity.java)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience fusedlocationprovider might also stop working propperly when the device is missing google play services  or even is missing an update in these services. in my case it was only invoquing the locationCallback a single time and would stop thereafter. After updating play services and restarting the device the normal reliable behaviour ensued.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the new runtime permissions in Android M that your code is not yet handling, I had one such case a while ago where my app would run in most of my devices, but when installed on new phones (using Android 6.0+) it would crash.

The cause was the lack of use of **explicit permission requests** in runtime.

you could try the following:

```
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        Bundle tmpSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;


        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            Toast.makeText(this, "Please accept the permission so you can use the location services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERM_REQUEST);

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERM_REQUEST);

            // MY_PERM_REQUEST is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }



        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || currentapiVersion <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            //Execute location service call if user has explicitly granted ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION..
            // use location services 
        }
```

The async permissions' request will return calling this callback:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERM_REQUEST: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                    //do whatever you want with your location API
                    // everything went well, use the location services


                } else {

                    // permission denied. Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
```

You could also check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) mentioned by @Blackkara

Let me know if this helped =)

Comment: @Nathan O'Kane  have you been able to solve your problem? let me know if this helped =)